# Create own JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a very simple Jquery Plugin. What it does is return the parent of the element. I searched and tried many different methods, still can't get it to run.

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    getParent:function(){

        return this.each(function(){$(this).parent()}); 

    }


    });
})(JQuery);
```

in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
alert($("#demos").getParent());
    });
</script>
```

it should alert the parent of the $("#demos")

Comment: I think the result from `this.each`isn't an array, by the way this function already exists : http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: BTW your function should be named `getParents()` if it returns more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo here:

Replace `JQuery` with `jQuery`.

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    getParent:function(){
        return this.each(function(){$(this).parent()}); 
    }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
console.log($("#demos").getParent());
});

<div id="parent">
    <div id="demos"></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PuUgc/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your plugin. It's `jQuery`, not `JQuery`.

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    getParent:function(){

        return this.each(function(){$(this).parent()}); 

    }


    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `this.each()` returns just the items in `this`. So you will not get the parents by doing an each but only the selected item again.

If you would do just...

```
 return $(this).parent();
```

...you would get what you want.